# Bash variable expansion can't be combined with time command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

I was writing a small shell script in bash to measure the speed of several executables using the `time` command. Because I wanted to time several different programs, to avoid repeating myself I saved the time command and the format string I wanted and tried to use variable expansion (testing the performance of `ls` as an example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

timer="/usr/bin/time -f 'elapsed time: %E' --"
$timer ls 1>/dev/null
```

The `time` command is supposed to use the `--` to separate its options (in this case a format string) from the command it's supposed to time. However, in this script `time` insists on trying to execute my format string and fails with

```
/usr/bin/time cannot run time:: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
'elapsed
```

But if I put the whole command on one line with no variable expansion it correctly recognizes the format string and executes `ls`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/usr/bin/time -f 'elapsed time: %E' -- ls 1>/dev/null
```

produces "elapsed time: 0:00.00"

I ended up just typing out the whole command on each line to get it to run, but I was curious if anyone could explain why variable expansion doesn't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in `$timer` is split on `$IFS` (spaces), and used as separate arguments. It is not expanded and then evaluated as bash code.

Your command `$timer ls` is therefore equivalent to:

```
"/usr/bin/time" "-f" "'elapsed time:" "%E'" "--" "ls"
```

The correct way to do this in your case is using a function:

```
timer() {
  /usr/bin/time -f 'elapsed time: %E' -- "$@"
}
timer ls
```

PS: This problem is automatically pointed out by [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a BASH array to store command line:

```
timer=(/usr/bin/time -f 'elapsed time: %E' --)
"${timer[@]}" ls
```